# python os module does not recognize ~ as shortcut for the user home directory

Tags: python, macos

I want my python script to change to a new directory using ~ as a shortcut for the home directory (so I can use the script on several different computers with different home directory names):

```
os.chdir('~/google_drive/2014-11-05-QiimeAnalysis/quality_filtering/)
```

This, however generates an error. Python doesn't seem to be able to recognize ~:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/google_drive/2014-11-05-QiimeAnalysis/quality_filtering/'
```

Why does this happen and is there a way around it? I have python 3.4 on OsX Yosemite.

Comment: P.S. That's not really a "relative" path.  Relative paths are relative to the current directory, like "./foo/file" or just implicitly "foo/file", i.e. not starting with "/".

Comment: OK, thanks! Changed the wording of the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) to expand the `~` into an actual path:

```
os.chdir(os.path.expanduser('~/google_drive/2014-11-05-QiimeAnalysis/quality_filtering/'))
```